# Make a Riemannian metric real analytic in some coordinates

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose I have a smooth (high dimensional) Riemannian manifold, and fix a base point $x_0$. Can I pick a coordinate system near $x_0$ such that the metric is real analytic in some of the variables (maybe just in the first variable)? I know that I cannot necessarily make it real analytic in *all* the variables, but is it possible to always make it partially real analytic?

Comment: On a surface, if the Gauss curvature is not a real analytic function of arc length along geodesics in any direction, you can't do it. I think that is not hard to arrange using known results about prescribed curvature.

Comment: Take the Euclidean space $\mathbb R^n$ for $n \geq 2$ and perturb it by a bump function. That won't be analytic at any point on the boundary of the support of the bump function.

Answer (score 4):

Ryan Budney's approach works easily for a surface conformal to the flat Euclidean plane. Perturb by rescaling the Euclidean metric to $g=e^u g_{\text{Euclid}}$. The Gauss curvature is $K_g=-e^{-u}\Delta u/2$, for $\Delta$ the Euclidean Laplace operator. As a first attempt, take $u_0=e^{-1/(r^2-1)^2}$ with $r^2=x^2+y^2$, for $r<1$, and $u_0=0$ for $r\ge 1$.

The rotational symmetry is useful because we can see geometrically that the Laplace operator gives a negative value, as the second derivatives near the origin are all negative, so positive curvature. Quotienting opposite sides of a big rectangle together, we get a deformed flat torus. The Gauss--Bonnet theorem tells us that the integral of the Gauss curvature is zero, so it is negative somewhere. Just looking at the picture, you can see that it is negative just inside the unit disk: shape like a fried egg.
The Gauss curvature is positive near the origin, negative further away, and then everywhere zero outside the unit disk.
For our purposes, you really don't need any computation: once we see that the Laplacian is positive near the origin, by analyticity inside the unit disk, the Laplacian is nonzero on dense open set. By rotation invariance, that set is a set of circles. With a bit of computation, you can check it is just one circle, I think.

This is sufficient to get the result with some effort, but to avoid some computation, instead try
$$u(x,y)=u_0(x-1/2,y)+u_0(x+1/2,y),$$
supported in two disks, tangent at the origin.
Again we have Gauss curvature positive near $(x,y)=(\pm 1/2,0)$, negative just inside the unit disks around these points, and then zero outside those disks.
If this metric is real analytic in one variable $u$, near such a point, in some coordinates $(u,v)$, the level sets of the other variable $v$ form a foliation whose leaves are smooth curves on which the Gauss curvature is analytic in $u$ on each leaf.
In particular, if Gauss curvature vanishes on an interval of a leaf, it vanishes everywhere, i.e. none of the leaves enters or exists either of the two disks.
So the leaf touching a boundary point of either disk stays on that boundary.
But then the leaf at the origin stays on the boundary of both disks, a single point, a contradiction.

In all dimensions $n\ge 3$, perturb by rescaling the Euclidean metric to $g=e^{2u} g_{\text{Euclid}}$. The scalar curvature is $R_g=-\frac{4(n-1)}{n-2}e^{-(n+2)u/2}\Delta e^{(n-2)u/2}$, for $\Delta$ the Euclidean Laplace operator. So again we take the same $u_0$ and the same $u$, and the same argument shows that the scalar curvature is zero outside the unit balls around the points, nonzero everywhere inside except on a sequence of spheres, probably just a single sphere. Writing Cartesian coordinates $(x,y)=(x,y_1,\dots,y_{n-1})$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, again, we argue about coordinates $(u,v)=(u,v_1,\dots,v_{n-1})$.

Comment: Great answer; can it be made to work in high dimensions?